# applying a Compute heavy operation to all elements of a slice concurrently

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have got a slice
`problemArray := []int{77,44,34,752,12}`
and I have to perform a compute heavy operation on all the elements of the slice luckily i can perform the operation concurrently lets say my function is as follows

```
func ComputeHeavyOperation(num int) int {
     time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
     return num * 2
```

and i would like to get the response like that

```
output := SomeNewFunc(problemArray, ComputeHeavyOperation)
fmt.Println(output)
```

and the output will be like `{144,88,68,1504,24}`
the issue to write SomeNewFunc, or may be any other way if i'm doing it in a wrong manner.

here is what i have tried

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func mathematicalCompute(container []int, c chan int) {
    for _, n := range container {
        go func(ch chan int) {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            ch <- n * 2
        }(c)
    }
    defer close(c)
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    c := make(chan int)
    mathematicalCompute(nums, c)
    for result := range c {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }

}
```

and it only outputs

```
Hello World
```

I think that the channel is getting closed even before it can recieve and i commented out the `defer close(c)` and it gives the following output

````
10
10
10
10
10
[T+2000ms]
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox3588770438/prog.go:21 +0xdb```
````

Comment: Yes, you are closing the channel too soon. See https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups for a fix, but put `wg.Wait(); close(c)` into its own goroutine. Pay attention to how i is copied and read the linked FAQ entry.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use a waitgroup to make `mathematicalCompute` wait for each goroutine to complete its execution. Since you're simply modifying the elements of a slice, you can actually forgo using a channel!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func mathematicalCompute(container []int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := range container {
        wg.Add(1)
        i := i
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            container[i] *= 2
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    mathematicalCompute(nums)
    for result := range nums {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

If you want to preserve the original slice, you can initialize a new slice of the same length, and use `i, value := range container` to populate `newSlice[i] = n*2`.

If you still want to use a channel, you can write to an unbuffered channel (similar to what you're already doing), just make sure that receiving the values occur concurrently so that you avoid a deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func mathematicalCompute(container []int, c chan int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, n := range container {
    n := n
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            c <- n * 2
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    defer close(c)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    c := make(chan int)
    go mathematicalCompute(nums, c)
    for result := range c {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

And if you want to use a channel but have printing occur strictly after processing, you can always use a buffered channel with a buffer of size `len(container)` by initializing the channel with `c := make(chan int, len(nums))`. This way the writers can write to the channel without having to wait for a receiver to first pick up previously passed values.